# Change JFrame Window buttons

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've created a normal window with 3 buttons (minimize,maximize,close)
But i want to change the Window bar to containe the title and the close button only

I did it before with one line but i forget how to make it

This is my code :

```
        frame.setSize(60, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(10,10);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Why did you delete your other question. I wrote an answer to it that will help you!

Comment: when i ask question that's mean i really need help , but people here give me dislikes and they don't answer me , that's why , for you thank you so much :) , but you were talking about any question please because in the last two days i just asked 2 questions one about Chrome and one about delphi function to delete exe file MainIcon ?

Comment: You deleted the question about your program terminating immediately just as I spent time writing an answer. You wasted my time.

Comment: i said i'm sorry :( , i'm new here so i could make some misstakes , do you still have the answer , i will undelete it :) :)

Comment: I don't have the answer. It was a good one too. I don't want to write it again. Stop worrying about the voting.

Comment: Voting :( , do you really though that i was thinking about the voting ? i have a problem and you helped me but i closed the question , so i felt that what i've done is a bad thing , i was worrying about you , thank you anyway and i found the solution that's why i closed the question :( and good-bye

 **Solution :** Repeat Application.processmessage; that's the solution

Comment: No, that is not the solution. That's a busy loop. Clearly you are not interested in learning.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  My guess is that this is another nom de plume of the poster who was interested in grabbing passwords and splitting memos in recent weeks.  Same behaviour:  not interested in Delphi solutions without specific code.  He was asking about deleting main icons from Exes earlier this weekend.

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to say exactly maybe because of my poor english but i'm using JAVAfor making games and i'm using delphi in my university club and there we work in different subjects (in my level we are just studying the basics with c language  ) but i want to work in an advanced level by working with delphi with other things (i'm begginer in programming) , **i think that i gave you a little idea about my life so i think that you could understand me better because i thought that you have a wrong idea about the poster :)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I did it before with one line but i forget how to make it

I don't think you did it before because Swing doesn't support this on a JFrame.

Maybe you used a `JDialog` before? This is the behaviour of a dialog.

However a JDialog should generally only be used as a popup window of a main JFrame. A JDialog does not appear in the task bar and if the dialog loses focus it is not easy to get back unless you tab through all the open windows.

Comment: I'm a beginner in java and in all of my life i've maked 3 From projects and i remember that i changed it in one of them but i don't remember , i don't know swing or not (i don't know if is there other thing than swing) but i remember that i did it before :) , do you know how to make it with JDialog ?

Comment: `do you know how to make it with JDialog ?` - I already told you it is the default behaviour. You create a dialog the same way you create a frame except you use `JDialog`.